# I have 3 images and i want to show them in 1 figure using subplot but they are too small, how can i make them bigger and more clear?

Tags: image, matlab-figure, subplot, figure, grayscale

Here are the 3 images i want to include in 1 figure but with a greater size for each

```
subplot(1,3,1)
imshow(image);
title('ORIGINAL IMAGE');

subplot(1,3,2);
imshow(B);
title('IMAGE AFTER LOCAL HISTOGRAM EQUALIZATION');

subplot(1,3,3);
imshow(F);
title('DIFFERENCE IN BOTH IMAGES');
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do it is the following:

```
Pos_size=[100 100 900 400]; %this is just a variable I put at the top of the file so I don't have to look through my script to change it. 
                            %[X1 Y1 width heigth] X1 is right side position, Y1 is bottom side position on your screen, 
                            %X1 and Y1 you use to center the figure when it opens.
h1=figure(1); %before your subplot, opens a figure and saves the handle as h1, alternatively you can use hf=gcf; as it will grab the handle of the latest figure
set(h1,'Position',Pos_size); %sets the position and size of the figure with handle h1
```

If you put this above your subplots it should work